# cnn using tensorflow for own image set - what should be the tfrecord format

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have an image data set of size 600 x 400 each and I have converted each of the images to TFRecord format. But I am unable to figure out how to use this data? I have seen the imagenet dataset and found only one single binary file (when extracted it form [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz://)).

Is it that for an image dataset there will be only one TFRecord or each individual images will have their own TFRecord files?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow doesnt look for single tfrecord file. So feel free and point your "data directory" and "train directory" to the location which has set of tfrecord files.

Also, keep in mind files should be in respective directories based on their names like TRAIN-*.tfrecord files in "train directory".

Answer can be more specific if you mentioned what model of TF you are targeting to run on these TF record files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain how to load the data set that I have i.e in my `train_directory` I have 5 label folders with the name `label_i` (i={1,2,3,4,5}).

Comment: ^ And in each `label_i` folder I have individual TF Record files of the images.

Comment: That wrong! Donot create separate TFRecord files for each "label"/"class" folder. While generating TFrecord files point to parent data_dir that has label directories inside it and specify in build_dataset script how much of those images you want in training and how much in evaluation